# Setting up Samba for File sharing w/ Linux Host for Windows Clients

Tags: linux, rhel, samba

Im trying to set up Samba on a Server that I recently built. I created a user group and was following a guide for the set up process and got stuck. After giving the user group `ShareGroup` permissions to the folder `DataShare` I tried running this command `chcon -Rt samba_share_t DataShare` and was met with this message `chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file 'DataShare'` Im not sure what this means or how to fix it.

Im having trouble finding a guide to fully set up samba for file sharing with windows machines, I you guys know of a good guide it would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I'm on RHEL 8.0

Comment: I used to do windows > linux samba networking, this isn't intended as a real answer, just a reminder to make sure once you get it set up  that users can change or delete or add files, from windows, that was a little permissions thing I remember not being immediately intuitive.

Comment: So are you saying that I cant restrict cliant windows users from r/w/x permissions?

Comment: No, I was not trying to answer your larger question, just adding a note of something to watch out for that is not always obvious when following the various setup guides. If users don't have execute or write permissions they can't do anything with the data, they can't even open directories, they can't save, it's essentially worthless unless it's intended to be a read only remote data store.

Comment: I understand that. I just didnt understand you comment at first. limiting permission would make it workthless

Comment: My recollection is that when setting up a share with what seem reasonable defaults, you can end up with a situation where users can't create new files, or really use the stuff in any practical way. Just something to watch out for, for example, we did not notice this for a few days until people realized they were unable to create new documents. This may have teen related to the samba user permissions, I can't remember, don't have my notes, sorry.

Comment: Is SELINUX enabled on the system?

Comment: @Lizardx perfect makes sence thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Nasir Riley How would I check that?

Comment: I used sestatus and its showing that its disabled

Comment: Then you need to turn it on before adding the SELinux context.

Comment: Ill give that a try

Comment: alright I enabled it and tried ```chcon -Ft samba_share_t DataShare``` and its giving me ```chcon: failed to change context of 'DataShare' to 'system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0': Operation not permitted```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to SELinux. I recommend to read how to properly relabel the directory for samba share using SELinux.